# SQLite Connections Drifting? (Network Share - Available Offline)

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm connecting to an SQLite database over a network share using the python sqlite3 module. There are 3 computers connecting to the database, but they seem to have drifted in terms of what they believe is in the database. I printed the table I am interested a couple of times and got the following results:

1/ This is how I found the table. Something has already gone wrong here as row 3 and 4 have an end time but not a start. Note row 5 is running on EDI-8433H5J:

```
Row         Status      Host         Start                       End
----------  ----------  -----------  --------------------------  --------------------------
0           F           EDI-26WDF5J  2014-04-15 12:02:32.152000  2014-04-15 23:10:39.664000
1           R           EDI-5RRXXX1  2014-04-16 04:49:12.853000
2           R           EDI-26WDF5J  2014-04-16 09:04:14.556000
3           S                                                    2014-04-16 04:49:12.822000
4           S                                                    2014-04-16 09:13:16.596000
5           R           EDI-8433H5J  2014-04-16 09:13:16.643000
6           W
```

2/ EDI-26WDF5J fails its run and writes an 'F' status to row 2. But where are the row 5 entries for EDI-8433H5J?

```
Row         Status      Host         Start                       End
----------  ----------  -----------  --------------------------  --------------------------
0           F           EDI-26WDF5J  2014-04-15 12:02:32.152000  2014-04-15 23:10:39.664000
1           R           EDI-5RRXXX1  2014-04-16 04:49:12.853000
2           F           EDI-26WDF5J  2014-04-16 09:04:14.556000  2014-04-16 09:51:50.592000
3           S                                                    2014-04-16 04:49:12.822000
4           W
5           W
6           W
```

3/ EDI-5RRXXX1 then fails the run it is doing and writes an 'F' status to row 1. It has registered the update from EDI-26WDF5J.

```
Row         Status      Host         Start                       End
----------  ----------  -----------  --------------------------  --------------------------
0           F           EDI-26WDF5J  2014-04-15 12:02:32.152000  2014-04-15 23:10:39.664000
1           F           EDI-5RRXXX1  2014-04-16 04:49:12.853000  2014-04-16 09:54:14.967000
2           F           EDI-26WDF5J  2014-04-16 09:04:14.556000  2014-04-16 09:51:50.592000
3           S                                                    2014-04-16 04:49:12.822000
4           W
5           W
6           W
```

4/ Now EDI-8433H5J fail its run and writes an 'F' status to row 5. But the statuses of rows 1 and 2 are as they were before they were changed.

```
Row         Status      Host         Start                       End
----------  ----------  -----------  --------------------------  --------------------------
0           F           EDI-26WDF5J  2014-04-15 12:02:32.152000  2014-04-15 23:10:39.664000
1           R           EDI-5RRXXX1  2014-04-16 04:49:12.853000
2           R           EDI-26WDF5J  2014-04-16 09:04:14.556000
3           S                                                    2014-04-16 04:49:12.822000
4           S                                                    2014-04-16 09:13:16.596000
5           F           EDI-8433H5J  2014-04-16 09:13:16.643000  2014-04-16 10:16:06.728000
6           W
```

It's like EDI-8433H5J has a completely different database to EDI-26WDF5J and EDI-5RRXXX1.

Note, this is being executed on a windows share, and I also had the "available offline" option for the folder containing the database on all the machines. Could this be causing alternative realities to exist between the different connections?

I can't seem to recreate the problem manually, so I'm a bit stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Conclusion**

So, I guess the moral of the story is don't attempt a network shared SQLite database with offline file access as, as Andrew Medico stated, Windows (*nix too?) will not be able to merge the database successfully (there were some syncing errors for the database file). This may have been what caused different versions of the database to appear on different machines.

Comment: `I also had the "available offline" option` - I bet that's not going to work well...

Comment: Yes, I thought this might be part of the problem, I was just surprised that they didn't come back into line with each other. I'm going to try closing and the reopening the connections while the simulations are running in the hope that it will cause a refresh.

Comment: "Available offline" just means you could use the folder offline, not that you necessarily are using it offline. Using Windows' offline folders feature with SQLite databases definitely would not work, though - Windows does not understand the SQLite format so eventually one copy would have to overwrite another and changes would be lost.

Comment: Windows network file locking is not dependable, so using an SQLite file on a network share with multiple writers is not recommended (http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q5). You should consider moving up to a networked database server.

Comment: OK, Andrew, thanks, I'm coming to the same conclusion, although that is uncharted waters for me. Using SQLite was meant to be an upgrade from searching for a "finish" file on the network, but I'm wondering if that approach may have been more robust, after all.